# How to open a core data database?

Tags: database, sqlite, core-data, persistence

Is there any way in which I can view my core data database without having to load it programatically through the code?!

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to view the database directly using the sqlite3 command line tool.  The database should be stored in the following directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/{your application GUID}/Documents/{your application name}.sqlite
```

To view the database, just type in the following in a terminal (note, sqlite3 should already be installed on your system by default):

```
sqlite3 {your application name}.sqlite
```

You can then run regular SQL to view the data in the database.

Note, the following useful commands:

- **.help** - Shows sqlite specific commands and what they do
- **.tables** - Shows all tables in the database
- **.schema** {followed by table name} - Shows the create statement used to create the table
- **.quit** - Exits sqlite3

Comment: The file name and extension does not have to be `{your application name}.sqlite` . It is whatever you save it as, for example: `user.data` .

Comment: I am using firefox sqlite manager plugin; I am able to see table structures but no data in it. Although, if i make query from code, i am getting the records; I am also sure, its the exact path where i am searching. Any one facing this kind of problem? I am using XCode 6.3

Answer (score 5):

It depends what format the data store is (Core Data currently supports XML, binary, and SQLite persistent data stores). XML data stores can be viewed using a text editor. Binary data stores can only be accessed via code. You can open a SQLite data store via the sqlite command line or via any number of GUI SQLite browsers. Keep in mind, however, that the on-disk representation (in a data base or otherwise) is an implementation detail of how Core Data chooses to persist an object graph to disk. Don't rely on this format in *any* way except to satisfy your curiosity. If you are trying to track down a bug, there are much better ways than poking in the data store.

Answer (score 4):

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/{APP GUID}/Documents/your_xcdatamodel.sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator
find . -type f -name "*.sqlite"
```

It's the one that is: [Project_Name].sqlite

I'm using Navicat Premium Essentials to view the database.
In Finder, right click on:

```
Library Folder->Show View Options->Select Show Library Folder
```

This will enable you to navigate to open the file in any SQLite data browser (such as Navicat)

Answer (score 0):

you can go to Application Support folder (which is usually ~/Library/Application Support/YourAppname/) and view YourAppname.xml file.

Usually while in development CoreData storage is in XML format. You can change it in one of AppDelegate's methods (i presume you created Core-Data Application)