# Opening database of test app in iPad

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Is there a way for me to open the database of a test app in iPad? I have to manually insert data into it for some reason. So is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way that you can open the database. The file location should be as follows:

*home*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/

Depending on how you want to view it I would recommend checking out either [How to open a core data database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405549/how-to-open-a-core-data-database) or [How view data stored in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268102/how-view-data-stored-in-core-data)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have a question. In my User folder, only the Library folder is present and Applications folder is missing. Why is that?